# SAS ODS output won't print titles

Tags: sas

I am completely stuck here. Searching around yields no people facing a similar problem.

So, all I am trying to do is get some output into an rtf file from SAS. The output is just from a proc print statement. My code is as follows (I've modified it to reference one of SAS's built in data sets in case anybody wants to replicate it. My real code references my data files):

```
   ods rtf file="output.rtf";
   title"First 10 observations of the systolic variable in the heart dataset";
   proc print data=sashelp.heart(obs=10);
        var systolic;
        run;
   ods rtf close;
```

However, when I check "output.rtf", it only includes the output from the proc print statement, and NOT the title statement. Why is this the case? Looking through all the SAS documentation and questions on this site that I can find, this SHOULD work. I can't think of a reason why it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `bodytitle` to your `ODS RTF` line.  It will move the titles from the document header (as @Joe describes) into the document itself.

Comment: Note that this and other ODS RTF tips can be found on the [ODS RTF Tip Sheet](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsrtf/rtf-tips.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @rambles! I had looked through a SUGI paper about the ODS RTF but I guess I had misunderstood what the 'bodytitle' command did so I never tried it. Anyway, this works perfectly and does exactly what I need. Still, I am curious as to find out what is going on with my document headers. So far as I can recall, I haven't done anything to change the defaults, so the titles SHOULD still appear as headers...

Comment: Without `bodytitle`, they're likely being output in the header portion.  That you can't see them might be dependent on the 'view' you're using in Word, Libre Writer, etc.  Try clicking 'Header' then 'Edit header' in Word - I expect you'll see the titles then.

Answer (score 0):

ODS RTF will by default print titles in the header section of the RTF file.  When I run the above code, I get a light gray title in the header like I would expect.

If you're not getting that, and can confirm you are not hiding the header of your document for some reason, you should look at the current style and verify that the color of the title font is not set to the same as the background color for the header.

Comment: How do I check the current settings for the document header? I am pretty sure the problem isn't one of background color, because if I select all and manually change the color to something else, no header magically appears.